# Output sound to headphones and speakers

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, output

Im wondering if it is possible to output sound to both headphones and built in speakers at the same time. Iv searched but all i can find is references to possible attemps using android. but my application will be web based, using flash and AS3. Can anyone confirm if this is possible or not?

essentially im trying to make a set of DJ decks, and thus need to be able to listen to 2 sounds separately but at the same time (to beatmatch)

Many Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not without a very specific setup. Flash will only output one, globally mixed audio stream from the application. You cannot separate your sounds to be routed to separate outputs.

---

However, if you're not looking for a general setup but rather a one-off thing where you are able to control the machine it is supposed to be running on - there could be a way. If you are writing an Adobe AIR app, you could write *two separate* apps:

1. **App A** controls the UI and all the sound
2. **App B** just receives a sound stream from the first app and plays it

**App A** then routes the "headphone track" to **App B** and plays the "main track" as normal.
You could then (maybe) use an application such as [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) to route the sound from **App A** and **App B** to separate outputs (where one could be the headphones and the other would go to some speakers.)

This all is very dependent on your sound card. You'll most likely need an external sound card to handle the two separate audio streams.